# Why would echoing an nbsp make a difference? (PHP)

Tags: php, echo, fread

I have a script which opens a file then prints its contents (for a long, silly reason that doesn't bear explaining).  The issue i have is, it often refuses to work, unless i echo some other text first.  The code below doesn't work, but if i put
`echo "a";`  or  `echo "&nbsp;";` first, it does.  Even more strange, `echo " ";` is insufficient.

What does echoing some text do?

```
//...a bunch of code to get the file name
if(file_exists($file))
    {
        $fp=fopen($file, "r");
        $temp = fread( $fp, filesize($file));
        echo $temp;
    } 
else 
    { 
    echo $file." not found<br /><br />";
    }
```

Comment: Does it work if you use file_get_contents instead of fopen and fread?

Comment: Try http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php.  What is the size of the file?  I have had issues like this for < 4K of output data.

Comment: Use [`readfile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) instead of `fread(fopen())`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$filelen = @readfile($file);
if ($filelen===FALSE) {
    echo "{$file} not found <br /><br />";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions everyone, but i'm afraid neither ob_flush(), flush() or readfile() solved my issue. I've put a kludge in for the moment.  given that my whole solution is one giant kludge i don't feel too bad about a little one...